# Allow my app to be chosen when a URL the intent.view intent is passed?

Tags: android

I am wanting to do a similar thing to the Google+ app, as when you click a Google+ link in, say, and e-mail app it prompts you to choose either the browser or the Google+ app.

How can I implement a function like this into my app? I have tried searching, but struggled as I don't think I was using the correct keywords :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by adding proper `<intent-filer>` inside your `<activity>` in Application `manifest file`

```
  <activity android:name="">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
         <data android:host="domain_name" android:scheme="http"></data>
         <data android:host="domain_name" android:scheme="http"></data>
     <intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

`These <activity> is called whenever another app with these <intent-filter> start implicit action with Intent.ACTION_VIEW also adding category and data inside the intent.data and intent.scheme`

Comment: How do I get the URL? I have tried it using the `String url2 = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't worry, figured it out. (You have to use intent.getDataString())

Comment: `Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();` Now you can set `data`-->`wenView.loadUrl(data)` to load the url inside your activity.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:host="YOUR_DOMAIN.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
    <data android:host="www.YOUR_DOMAIN.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Just swap out the `YOUR_DOMAIN` for your own domain, and it should be working as expected to.